# C# access ref variable passed to window, from another window function

Tags: c#, multithreading, ref

```
public int stop = 0;
public void main()
{
    Thread thrDoStuff = new Thread(()=> dostuff(ref stop));
    testWindow window = new testWindow(ref stop);
}

public void dostuff(ref int stop)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (stop != 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    //exit from loop and do other stuff
}
```

`stop` is a variable i want to use inside the function `dostuff`, to know when exit from the loop.
window is a window...from where i would like to be able to change value to `stop` variable.
for example from a button click, or from a thread started from the window.

here the window code:

```
public readonly DispatcherTimer Start = new DispatcherTimer();
public testWindow (ref int stop )
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //i know that if i change the stop value here, the change will be also visible from  dostuff function. but i want to change the stop value from a botton click for example
        
    Start.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
    Start.Tick += workloop;
    Start.IsEnabled = true;
 }

private void buttonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //i would like to change value to sotp variable here, and the change has to be reflected to dostuff function
}

private void workloop(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //i want this function to be run only once
    Start.IsEnabled = false;
    
    //i would like to change value to stop function also from here
}
```

how can i do it??

Comment: Any reason you're re-inventing (sort of, without actually implementing a type) `CancellationToken(Source)`?

Comment: thank you for the input,
i was not aware of CancellationToken.
i will take some time to read the documentation and test.

Answer (score 0):

There are several built-in solutions for this problem, so you don't need to re-invent the wheel as it was indicated by [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever).

Prior `Task`s we have usually used [`ManualResetEventSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim) for this purpose.

```
static void Main()
{
    var cancellationSignal = new ManualResetEventSlim();
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(200);
        cancellationSignal.Set();
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (cancellationSignal.IsSet)
        {
            cancellationSignal.Dispose();
            break;
        }
                    
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}
```

As you can see this class can be used other types of signalling as well.

With `Task`s we have a purpose built class for cancellation, called [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource):

```
static void Main()
{
    var cancellationSignal = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(200);
        cancellationSignal.Cancel();
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (cancellationSignal.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            cancellationSignal.Dispose();
            break;
        }
                    
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
}
```

---

Please bear in mind that both classes implement `IDisposable` so we have to make sure that we have disposed them after usage.